# How to get a collection of all child elements that have parents with ID attributes?

Tags: javascript

I have a situation where I need to collect a collection of elements that have parents with IDs.  So if

My scenario

```html
<table>
 <thead></tead>
 <tbody>
   <tr id="row1"><td><div class="pro_fname">name</div></td></tr>
   <tr id="row2"><td><div class="pro_fname">name</div></td></tr>
   <tr id="row3"><td><div class="pro_fname">name</div></td></tr>
   <tr><td><div class="pro_fname">name</div></td></tr>
   <tr><td><div class="pro_fname">name</div></td></tr>
   <tr><td><div class="pro_fname">name</div></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

From JavaScript, how can I guarantee to store the first three `fname` class elements into a list, but disregard the other `fname` class elements, all because the first 3 have parent ID's on  elements?

Below is my initial attempt...

```js
//collect all desired elements
var objFirstNames = document.getElementsByClassName("pro_fname");
...
...

//call function to check against the array type objects collected. arguments will grow...
//lets just focus on first names
checkInputValuesObjects(objFirstNames, objLastNames, objAttEmails, ...);

//filter values where parent ID's exist
function checkInputValuesObjects() {
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
     if (arguments[i][0].parentNode.parentNode.id.length) {
       //then I can do something with these specific elements...
       console.log(arguments[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

...but I'm having a hard time, specifically through Firefox Console, if I am truly capturing only 3 objects, and not all 6....

Comment: Whats the desired outcome? The first 3, or all the elements?

Comment: the first 3, BECAUSE they have parent ID's on their tr elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
document.querySelectorAll('tr[id] div');
```

Will first select all `tr` with an `id` attribute, then get all the `div` elements inside.

```js
const ee = document.querySelectorAll('tr[id] div');
ee.forEach(e => console.log(e.className));
```

```html
<table>
 <thead></tead>
 <tbody>
   <tr id="row1"><td><div class="pro_fname">name</div></td></tr>
   <tr id="row2"><td><div class="pro_fname">name</div></td></tr>
   <tr id="row3"><td><div class="pro_fname">name</div></td></tr>
   <tr><td><div class="pro_fname">name</div></td></tr>
   <tr><td><div class="pro_fname">name</div></td></tr>
   <tr><td><div class="pro_fname">name</div></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The above will yield:

```
pro_fname
pro_fname
pro_fname
```

Comment: Ok, so In this case, I should look at it from an outside -> In perspective, not from Inside -> out perspective.  Many thanks!

Comment: Yes, keep in mind that CSS always works from the outside to the inside. For example CSS doesn't (really) have [a parent selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector). So start on the outside, and work your way in ;)